# How do i force wpf ValidationRules binding?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, validationrules

I have a textbox for example that is bound via the mvvm pattern like this:

```
<TextBox VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" Validation.ErrorTemplate="{StaticResource ValidationErrorTemplate}">
            <TextBox.Text>
                <Binding Path="Entity.LastName" NotifyOnValidationError="True">
                    <Binding.ValidationRules>
                        <validations:MandatoryValidationRule/>
```

This specific rule checks if any value was entered to the textbox.
However, this rule is activated only when a user enters some text and then deletes it.
Most times, when a user leaves out a blank field, its because he forgot to fill it.

So, how can i, from the view model, force all validation rules to be checked before i allow the user to actually save the data?

It would be also nice if i could somehow do it to all the controls at once.

Thank u.

Answer (score -1):

You can force the rules to update automatically once the Window has bee loaded so that the blank fields will indicate an error:

```
public void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    textbox1.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty).UpdateSource();
    textbox2.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty).UpdateSource();
}
```

or, you can implement `IDataErrorInfo` and update your Text binding so that it `ValidatesOnDataErrors`

```
 <Binding Path="Entity.LastName" NotifyOnValidationError="True" ValidatesOnDataErrors="True">
```

Here's a simple [example](http://www.eidias.com/Blog/2012/7/2/simple-validation-in-wpf-mvvm-using-idataerrorinfo) on how to implement `IDataErrorInfo`

Comment: Thank u for ur answer but:
1. I have already implemented my validations rule using ValidationRule class and don't want to re-implement them.
2. I dont want to write any code behind.
3. I don`t want the error to be displayed by default even before the user tried to save.